# How to input module in spyder properly?

Tags: python, data-science, spyder

I am really confuse how i can solved this problem, the module won't import, how i can import twitter scraper module in spyder

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

begin_date = dt.date(2020,5,19)
end_date = dt.date(2020,5, 20)

limit = 1000
lang = 'english'

tweets = query_tweets("#MahasiswaUPITolakBayarUKT",begindate = begin_date, enddate = end_date, limit = limit, lang = lang)
```

Comment: could you say what you mean by "the module won't import"?  error messages really help here.  what have you tried, e.g. how did you install the package?

Comment: Please provide info on how you installed twitterscraper. Generally, the environment where you installed twitterscraper should be the same exact environment you use for running your python app/script.